# Agar.io style ripple effect for canvas arcs

Tags: javascript, canvas

I really love how they created the online game agario. I have been thinking: "How did they created this ripple effect for the edges?"

[image]

There are a few things I could think of:

1) The border is made of many vector points, therefore allowing flexible animation of the border.

2) The border is a predefined gif like animation.

3) There are many invisible pixels around the edge. They loop around the arc and activate a few groups of those pixels, therefore creating an illusion that the border is "contracting" and "retracting".

How can something like this be done in HTML5 canvas? Do you think one of my 3 ideas for a solution apply or is it more complex than that?

Comment: @markE just enter a guest name and hit play and you will see the effect https://agar.io/

Comment: Better than an image ; )

Comment: @markE http://flockdraw.com/gallery/view/2097796

Comment: Might not be a very good drawing but you can see what I mean. The edges are somehow liquid. Kind of like some bacteria or cell movement of the membrane. I think this might only be achievable with svg or maybe even creating a canvas polygon and animating the points. Not sure what the best method would be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What you can do is repeatedly draw a sine wave around the circumference of a circle.**

[image]

The equations to get the sine wave [x,y] point at any angle around a circle are:

```
var x = centerX+(radius+amplitude*Math.sin(sineCount*angle))*Math.cos(angle);
var y = centerY+(radius+amplitude*Math.sin(sineCount*angle))*Math.sin(angle);
```

The `centerX, centerY and radius` define the circle.

The `amplitude` determines how far from the circle's circumference the sine wave will travel.

The `sineCount` is the number of complete sine waves that will be drawn around the circle.

The `angle` is the current angle around the circle which you desire the "sined" [x,y].

**Here's an example and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var radius=100;
var amp=10;
var sineCount=10;

ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=0;i<360;i++){
  var angle=i*Math.PI/180;
  var pt=sineCircleXYatAngle(cx,cy,radius,amp,angle,sineCount);
  ctx.lineTo(pt.x,pt.y);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

function sineCircleXYatAngle(cx,cy,radius,amplitude,angle,sineCount){
  var x = cx+(radius+amplitude*Math.sin(sineCount*angle))*Math.cos(angle);
  var y = cy+(radius+amplitude*Math.sin(sineCount*angle))*Math.sin(angle);
  return({x:x,y:y});
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Why didnt I think about that! You are right. We just make the radius go negative and positive using a sin wave. I really need to use the trig functions more. I will see if I didnt understand something.

Comment: How did you figure out that you had to do Math.PI / 180

Comment: I mean doing something like 180 / 180 gives a really interesting yet different result? why? How does that particular section work? I cant really imagine. Math.PI is the same as 180 degrees so why the difference?

Comment: It is easier to increment `i` in the for-loop in degrees because degrees are integers. But javascripts `.cos & .sin` methods only take radians. Therefore, I must convert the i-degrees into radians using `radians=degrees*Math.PI/180`. ;-)

Comment: Yes, `Math.PI` (which is expressed in radians) is exactly 180 degrees. ;-)

Comment: Oh yes! I remember the mathematical formula to convert radians to degrees and vice versa

Comment: I assume this is the formula you used. This absolutely makes sense now

Answer (score 3):

*(late reply but probably more accurate than the accepted answer)*

I was also wondering how this effect was done and since I couldn't find any informations about it I decided to dive into the obfuscated code.

Firstly, one should note that the cells are not circles but rather polygons. Every point of the polygon is constrained to keep the same distance from the center, which makes the calculations much easier. In addition each point has a velocity which is represented by a scalar (a positive velocity tends to move the point away from the center while a negative one will bring it closer). Whenever a point is out of the map or touches another point of a different cell, its velocity is decreased. At each iteration the velocity is added to the point and then increased by a small amount (natural decay).

With this set of rules and some (minor) additional constraints you should be able to reproduce this effect. I tried myself and [ended up with a pretty good result](https://twitter.com/flomine68/status/960172515053195265).

**Edit**: I also made a Scala.js fiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/FMoNM7c/0